# Samsung c430 & Ubuntu 19.04

Tags: printing, 19.04, samsung

After installing 19.04 I can no longer use my printer. Anything I try to print I get a blank page with error below.
I've tried to install a fresh copy of ubuntu and several versions of the printer drivers to no avail.
Note: it works perfectly with 18.04 - to double check I've just installed a VM with 18.04 and it works.

Any idea?

```
SPL ERROR - Undefined Command

     POSITION : 0x0 (0)

     SYSTEM   : emul/SPL/SPL

     LINE     :   481

     VERSION  : SPL_V10.48.01 09-17-2015

     ERROR CODE  : 11-1114
```

Comment: Same here, same error, no luck. Did you try filing a bug in Launchpad? And refer to this question.

Answer (score 2):

I use debian ,but i've solved the problem after a long search by installing CUPS 2.3 (the latest version).I've updated all cups packages in synaptic... it was avaiable on the unstable repo in debian , so i don't know about ubuntu .
CUPS 2.3 fixed my Samsung C430W printer!

Answer (score 0):

I'm also having this problem. A temporary workaround in my specific case was to uninstall the proprietary driver and install the printer again using the general driverless from the repositories (these should be installed by default). Using the printer driverless means that the options are pretty basic, though (I cannot print in B/W, for example).
Hope it helps.

Comment: What driver did you use exactly? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem with exactly the same printer and upgrade from kubuntu 18.10 to 19.04.

I fixed it by reinstalling cups:

```
root@kosyakov-XPS13:~# apt remove cups      

Reading package lists... 
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  bluez-cups cups hplip printer-driver-gutenprint printer-driver-hpcups printer-driver-splix
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 6 to remove and 3 not upgraded.
After this operation, 5,313 kB disk space will be freed.
...

root@kosyakov-XPS13:~# apt install bluez-cups cups hplip printer-driver-gutenprint printer-driver-hpcups printer-driver-splix

Reading package lists... 
Suggested packages:
  cups-pdf smbclient hplip-doc hplip-gui python3-notify2 gutenprint-doc gutenprint-locales
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  bluez-cups cups hplip printer-driver-gutenprint printer-driver-hpcups printer-driver-splix
0 upgraded, 6 newly installed, 0 to remove and 3 not upgraded.
Need to get 1,266 kB of archives.
...

Creating/updating hplip user account...
Processing triggers for dbus (1.12.12-1ubuntu1.1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.8.5-2) ...
root@kosyakov-XPS13:~#
```